# I am working with XML, is there a way to highlight text and wrap it with a custom tag? I am using Visual Studio Code

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, xml-parsing, tags

I want to take a sentence and wrap it with a custom tag like  is there a way to quickly highlight text and do this in any editor?